# Export Canvas Chart to PDF using JSPDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, canvas, jspdf

I am using jspdf for exporting canvas chart and related data in PDF format. I am able to fetch the data properly but not getting chart image in PDF. Below is my code:

```
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    
    var canvas = document.getElementById('graph');
    var canvasImg = canvas.toDataURL();
    console.log(canvasImg);

    var rows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < dataFFTvalues.length; ++i) {
        for (var j = 0; j < dataFFTvalues[i].length; ++j) {
            dataFFTvalues[i][j] = dataFFTvalues[i][j];
        }
        rows.push(dataFFTvalues[i]); //.join(',')
    }

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'http://domainname.com/portal/img/logo.png';

    img.onload = function(){
        doc.setFontSize(15);
        doc.addImage(img, 'PNG', 160, 5, 40 , 18);
        doc.text(90, 20, "Report");
        doc.setFontSize(10);
        doc.text(15, 40, "Below are the metric details : ");

        doc.autoTable(columns, rows, {startY: 85}); 
        doc.addPage();
        doc.internal.scaleFactor = 1.8;
        var width = doc.internal.pageSize.width;     
        doc.addImage(canvasImg, 'PNG', 5, 20, width-20, 70);
        doc.save('FFTcanvas.pdf');
    }
```

The rows and logo image is exporting correctly in PDF. But 'canvasImg' is not coming its coming blank. Console output for 'canvasImg':

data:image/png;base64,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......

Looking forward suggestion and help.

Comment: Have you tried passing the reference to the `<canvas>`-element instead of the base64 encoded string? According to the docs, that's possible: https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-addImage.html

Comment: I solved it. I placed the canvasImg code exactly above the addImage syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by changing some code:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();

var rows = [];
for (var i = 0; i < dataFFTvalues.length; ++i) {
    for (var j = 0; j < dataFFTvalues[i].length; ++j) {
        dataFFTvalues[i][j] = dataFFTvalues[i][j];
    }
    rows.push(dataFFTvalues[i]); //.join(',')
}

var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://domainname.com/portal/img/logo.png';

img.onload = function(){
    doc.setFontSize(15);
    doc.addImage(img, 'PNG', 160, 5, 40 , 18);
    doc.text(90, 20, "Report");
    doc.setFontSize(10);
    doc.text(15, 40, "Below are the metric details : ");

    doc.autoTable(columns, rows, {startY: 85}); 
    doc.addPage();
    doc.internal.scaleFactor = 1.8;
    var width = doc.internal.pageSize.width;   

    var canvas = document.getElementById('graph');
    var canvasImg = canvas.toDataURL();

    doc.addImage(canvasImg, 'PNG', 5, 20, width-20, 70);
    doc.save('FFTcanvas.pdf');
}
```

Placed canvas graph code exactly above the addImage() and worked perfectly:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('graph');
var canvasImg = canvas.toDataURL();
doc.addImage(canvasImg, 'PNG', 5, 20, width-20, 70);
```

Thank you.